# Bound service vs local object

Tags: android

It seems that bound services can be used when providing access to another object and to ensure data exchange. For example this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html) suggests to create an `AuthenticatorService` in order to allow the sync framework to access the beforehand defined class `Authenticator`.

> In order for the sync adapter framework to access your authenticator,
>   you must create a bound Service for it.

Why can't I just create a local Authenticator object? I could access it and data exchange would be possible as well. By default bound processes are run in the same process, so currently I don't see any advantage instead of using some nice code paradigms.

Comment: obviously because "sync adapter framework" is not a part of your application(and it is not bound to the same process) ... obviously you can use local object ... but then there will be no use of "sync adapter framework"

Comment: This makes sense. I will have to check where exactly the sync adapter framework is connected to the AuthenticatorService. I am following the linked tutorial and I was not aware that this framework actually is not managed by my app.

Comment: it is used to add account in "Settings=>Accounts" ... it is also used in synchronization API